# UTC to local timezone in a flask/jinja template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I know this has been asked before, and I'm still pulling my hair out trying to figure this one out. I've tried pytz, dateutil, and now flask_moment. Still having problems converting a MySQL table datetime, which is UTC, to display in the jinja2 template as local time, specifically UTC - 05:00 (EST).

My jinja2 for loop looks like this:

```
{% for data in items %}
    ...
   <td>{{data.loggedInBy}}</td>
   <td>{{data.timeIn.strftime('%I:%M %p')}}</td>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

I'm new to python/flask/jinja, so go easy on me, please. The documentation is pretty confusing for a noob such as myself. Can someone please walk me through getting my MySQL table to display the times in local timezone?

I feel like this is close, but getting errors with it. In **init**.py, I had:

```
from pytz import timezone

def datetimefilter(value, format='%I:%M %p'):
    tz = timezone('US/Eastern')
    dt = value
    local_dt = tz.localize(dt)
    local_dt.replace(hour=local_dt.hour + int(local_dt.utcoffset().total_seconds() / 3600))
    return local_dt.strftime(format)

flask_app.jinja_env.filters['datetimefilter'] = datetimefilter

jinja template had:

{% for data in items %}
...
<td>{{data.loggedInBy}}</td>
<td>{{data.timeIn | datetimefilter }}</td>
...
{% endfor %}
```

But this was giving me "ValueError: hour must be in 0..23"
From line:

```
local_dt.replace(hour=local_dt.hour + int(local_dt.utcoffset().total_seconds() / 3600))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

This is what ended up working for me, in this particular case, and I'm still not sure if it is going to give incorrect info during DST, but we'll see.

```
import pytz
from pytz import timezone
import tzlocal 

def datetimefilter(value, format="%I:%M %p"):
    tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern') # timezone you want to convert to from UTC
    utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')  
    value = utc.localize(value, is_dst=None).astimezone(pytz.utc)
    local_dt = value.astimezone(tz)
    return local_dt.strftime(format)

flask_app.jinja_env.filters['datetimefilter'] = datetimefilter
```

Then my jinja2 template looks like:

```
{% for data in items %}
...
<td>{{data.loggedInBy}}</td>
<td>{{data.timeIn | datetimefilter }}</td>
...
{% endfor %}
```

If there's any way to improve on this, I'm open to suggestions, but so far, this is the only way that I've found that works.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Localize is not going to change the timezone, but rather add the timezone information to a naive datetime object.  You say your datetime is coming from SQL and is in UTC, but is is a timezone aware datetime object?  If `value` is a datetime object that is aware it is UTC and not a naive datetime object you should change the timezone like this

```
tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')  # timezone you want to convert to from UTC
local_dt = value.astimezone(tz)
return local_dt.strftime(format)
```

If you get an error
`ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime`
then your `value` is a naive datetime object and you could make it time zone aware (as UTC) 1st and then get your localized datetime like this.

```
tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
tz_aware_dt = utc.localize(value)
local_dt = tz_aware_dt.astimezone(tz)
return local_dt.strftime(format)
```

There are a number of ways you could check to see if your datetime object is naive or not.  For instance, if it is aware of it's timezone `value.tzname()` will return the name of the timezone, otherwise it will return none.

> Timezone aware: `datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 4, 28, 26, 149703,
>   tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>)`
>
> Naive datetime object: `datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 9, 28, 26,
>   149703)`

Comment: Thanks Schechter, But it seems that even after your 2nd suggestion that I'm still getting the ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime. Closer, but still not quite workin' for me.

Comment: Yeah Schechter, looks like the line that reads `tz_aware_dt = utc.localize(value)` should be: `tz_aware_dt = utc.localize(value).astimezone(pytz.utc)` to actually make it aware

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @RyanGreever.  I think I had left 'value' where it should have been tz_aware_dt.    I've edited the answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: As of Python 3.6, astimezone() can be called on a naive datetime and it will be assumed to be in the local timezone. Watch out for that!

Answer (score 1):

[Flask-Moment](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Moment) is good to be used in this case. See the link for the detailed instruction.